# Following a tutorial but onSumbit(e) not printing to console

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am following along with this tutorial (https://medium.com/@beaucarnes/learn-the-mern-stack-by-building-an-exercise-tracker-mern-tutorial-59c13c1237a1) and am trying to print to console through the onSubmit function but this is not occurring and I do not know why. I've made sure to use the bind method, and everything seems to be referenced correctly.  What am I missing here?

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import DatePicker from 'react-datepicker';
import "react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css";

export default class CreateWorkout extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props); // Refers to the parent class constructorq

        this.onChangeUsername = this.onChangeUsername.bind(this);
        this.onChangeDescription = this.onChangeDescription.bind(this);
        this.onChangeReps = this.onChangeReps.bind(this);
        this.onChangeDuration = this.onChangeDuration.bind(this);
        this.onChangeDate = this.onChangeDate.bind(this);
        this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);

        this.state = {
            username:'',
            description: '',
            reps: 0,
            duration: 0,
            date: new Date(),
            users: []
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() { // Invoked immediately after a component is mounted
        this.setState({
            users: ['test user'],
            username: 'test user'
        });
    }

    onChangeUsername(e) {
       this.setState({
           username: e.target.value
       });
    }

    onChangeDescription(e) {
        this.setState({
            description: e.target.value
        });
    }

    onChangeReps(e) {
        this.setState({
            reps: e.target.value
        });
    }

    onChangeDuration(e) {
        this.setState({
            duration: e.target.value
        });
    }

    onChangeDate(date) { // Need to add a date picker library for this
        this.setState({
            date: date
        });
    }

    // Submit method for submitting an event of the form...
    onSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); 

        const workout = {
            username: this.state.username,
            description: this.state.description,
            reps: this.state.reps,
            duration: this.state.duration,
            date: this.state.date,
        };
        console.log(workout);

        window.location = '/'; // After form is submitted, the location is updated so the user is taken back to the home page
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h3>Create New Workout Log</h3>
                <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <label>Username: </label>
                        <select ref="userInput" required className="form-control" value={this.state.username} onChange={this.onChangeUsername}>
                            {
                                this.state.users.map(function(user) {
                                    return <option key={user} value={user}>{user}</option>;
                                })
                            }
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <label>Description: </label>
                        <input type="text" required className="form-control" value={this.state.description} onChange={this.onChangeDescription}/>
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <label>Reps: </label>
                        <input type="text" className="form-control" value={this.state.reps} onChange={this.onChangeReps}/>
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <label>Duration: </label>
                        <input type="text" className="form-control" value={this.state.duration} onChange={this.onChangeDuration}/>
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <label>Date: </label>
                        <div><DatePicker selected={this.state.date} onChange={this.state.onChangeDate}/></div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <input type="submit" value="Create Workout Log" className="btn btn-primary"/>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: **window.location = '/';** try to comment out this line.

Comment: Wow... Thank you!